# bash: Python import - Command not found for pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, terminal, python-import

***I am a beginner in Python using MacBook***

I want to import `pandas` in my Python script and I'm typing the following command below:

`import pandas as pd`

which results in:

> Error: -bash: import: command not found

**Questions:**

1. How can I enable import command. I used `#!/usr/bin/python` and `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as well but nothing happens after hitting enter.
2. I am importing `pandas` in a folder under Documents. I hope that's OK. I can't put the path where my Python is installed, since it is in Applications folder.

Comment: sounds like you’re typing that in the terminal? maybe you should reference the documentation on how to open a REPL shell for Python

Comment: Are you running the `import` command from a Python prompt of directly from your bash command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to open the Python prompt first.

Try this:

```
$ python
>>> import pandas as pd
```

Where `$` is the prompt in your bash shell, and the `>>>` is the prompt in your Python prompt.  Don't type these in.

Comment: In that case I get error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas"

Comment: That's fine, this is progress. This simply means pandas is not installed. From your bash shell run: 'pip install pandas'.  (Without the quotes, of course.)

Comment: I am trying but since I am new here, I am not able to due to minimum rep points. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running python code on shell script. I tried to get the same result by running shell script with python "import command" in it.

I created a file test.sh

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import pandas as pd
```

and the output was: test.sh: line 3: import: command not found

You need to run it as "/usr/local/bin/python test.py" or just "python test.py"